# scraping only discounted products

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to write a product scraping code from the category. I can scrape all the products in the category. however, products without discounts are scraped in vain.

I want to scrape according to the discount rate of the product in the category.

In the following example, if the discount on the product is more than 30%, it should continue to scrape, if it is small it should skip this product and continue to scrape it with the next product. . I couldn't figure out the if structure...

can you help me?

Full Code is here
https://codeshare.io/5Or9L0

---

**Annotation**

For now, I just want him to consider the rate on the site.

there are rates on the site. and I'm digging this ratio with code...

```
item['badge']=product_content.xpath('.//div[@class="badge highlight discount-badge"]/span/text()').extract_first()
```

I want the spider to do the scraping as follows. Do you think that's possible?

https://snipboard.io/lSxkrF.jpg

Answer (score 0):

here is formula:
You dont need to detect discount rate. You can calculate and if your condition not convenient with result after that just skip it:

```py
def find_discount(old_price, new_price, discount_limit):
    discount = 100 * round(float(old_price)/float(new_price), 2)
    return discount >= discount_limit

def parse_product_pages(self,response):

        item=TutorialItem()

        # Get the HTML block where all the products are listed
        # <ul> HTML element with the "products-listing small" class name
        content=response.xpath('//ul')
        print(content)
        # loop through the <li> elements with the "product-item" class name in the content
        for product_content in content.xpath('//li[@class="search-item col lg-1 md-1 sm-1  custom-hover not-fashion-flex"]'):
            ## other process...
            ## other process...
            ## other process...
            tmp_old_price = product_content.xpath('.//div[@class='price-container']/del[@class='price old product-old-price']/text()').extract_first().split()[0]
            # .split()[0] for selected count convert to float
            tmp_new_price = product_content.xpath('.//div[@class='price-container']/span[@class='price product-price']/text()').extract_first().split()[0]
            if filter_discount(tmp_old_price, tmp_new_price, 30) # for your example "30%"
                continue
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But that formula is not work my project. I was getting the following error. I changed the level settings, it doesn't make mistakes, but it doesn't scrape.

Comment: Last formula is here 

https://codeshare.io/G8EykD

.